# setState upon pressing creates new object

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

Before pressing there are only 3 buttons but after pressing any button as you can see there is 6 buttons

[image]

I'm trying to create rating system for my app, but whenever I press a button a new Button is created and I'm not quite sure why that happens.

If i try to run it without `setState()` and I press button no new object is created and that is what I want in the end.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Rating extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RatingState createState() => _RatingState();
}

class _RatingState extends State<Rating> {
  final List<IconData> iconsImage = [
    Icons.star,
    Icons.star,
    Icons.star,
    Icons.star,
  ];
  List<ButtonTheme> buttonsList = new List<ButtonTheme>();

  List<Widget> _buildButtons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      buttonsList.add(ButtonTheme(
        height: 20,
        minWidth: 40,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //When i press button new star is created not sure why
            setState(() {
              print(i);
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.star),
        ),
      ));
    }
    return buttonsList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text('Rate the homework',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 30,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Row(
              children: _buildButtons(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And where exactly is the new object created?

Comment: Try removing the`setState()`..

Comment: @jabli Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your **_buildButtons** method inside a **build** function.

**Reason**: `State Class in Stateful Widget are meant to hold and persist the state even during rebuild so that old state is remembered.`

> Here buttonsList is your state which will not be overwritten. So
>   Clicking button (which will set state) will push new button to an existing button list(not to
>   a newly created list).

**Solution**: `If you initialize you buttonsList inside a build function,it will also be reinitialized during re-build. So Clicking button (which will set state) will push new button to an newly created button list(not to a existing created list).`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Rating extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RatingState createState() => _RatingState();
}

class _RatingState extends State<Rating> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ButtonTheme> buttonsList = new List<ButtonTheme>();

    List<Widget> _buildButtons() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        buttonsList.add(ButtonTheme(
          height: 20,
          minWidth: 40,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //When i press button new star is created not sure why
              setState(() {
                print(i);
              });
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.star),
          ),
        ));
      }
      return buttonsList;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text('Rate the homework',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 30,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Row(
              children: _buildButtons(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it worked thx man! If i understand it right it didn't work before because upon pressing button i was creating new list right?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it solves your problem :)